# interpreting the value of estimate for odds ratio doing logistic regression in R

Tags: r, regression, interpretation

I'm currently evaluating clinical data using a logistic regression in R.

Sample data

```
set.seed(42)

age <- round(runif(100, min = 20, max = 95))
cancer <- sample(c(0, 1), 100, replace = TRUE)

data <- data.frame(age = age, cancer = cancer)

print(data)
```

Then I created the logistic regression model by

```
glm(cancer ~ age, data = data, family = "binomial")
```

For a first inspection I used summary(). As the estimate of the odds ratio for my age variable I get the value 0.08. I know for a fact that age has a positive influence on the likelihood of my outcome (cancer disease) so i would expect the value to be something higher than 1. Previously I worked with Stata and if for every year the RR of cancer increases by .08 it would show as 1.08. The value being lower than 1 makes me wonder if either R has a different way for the output of OR estimate for metric or did I maybe do something wrong during the creation of my regression model?

Comment: Hi tholori. Your question is great. It's fully reproducible, clear, succinct and useful. But it's not really about programming. Questions about interpretation of statistical results are best asked over at [stats.se]. However, the answer is simply that in R, the coefficients of a binomial glm are in the raw natural log format. Running `exp()` on the coefficients gives you the odds ratios. I'm voting to close as off-topic, but hopefully that gives you the answer you were looking for